# Speed up writing billions of rows to HDF5

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, hdf5, pytables

This is a continuation of the scenario I tried to discuss in my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251445/tips-to-store-huge-sensor-data-in-hdf5-using-pandas. Please read the question for more details about what follows.

Since the linked question above was closed as the subject was too broad, I did not get a chance to gather ideas from people more experienced at handling hundreds of gigabytes of data. I do not have any experience with that whatsoever, and I am learning as I go. I have apparently made some mistake somewhere, because my method is taking way too long to complete.

The data is as I described in the linked question above. I decided to create a node (group) for each sensor (with the sensor ID as the node name, under root) to store the data generated by each of the 260k sensors I have. The file will end up with 260k nodes, and each node will have a few GB of data stored in a Table under it. The code that does all the heavy lifting is as follows:

```
with pd.HDFStore(hdf_path, mode='w') as hdf_store:
    for file in files:
        # Read CSV files in Pandas
        fp = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(path, str(file).zfill(2)) + '.csv')
        df = pd.read_csv(fp, names=data_col_names, skiprows=1, header=None,
                         chunksize=chunk_size, dtype=data_dtype)

        for chunk in df:
            # Manipulate date & epoch to get it in human readable form
            chunk['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(chunk['DATE'], format='%m%d%Y', box=False)
            chunk['EPOCH'] = pd.to_timedelta(chunk['EPOCH']*5, unit='m')
            chunk['DATETIME'] = chunk['DATE'] + chunk['EPOCH']

            #Group on Sensor to store in HDF5 file
            grouped = chunk.groupby('Sensor')
            for group, data in grouped:
                data.index = data['DATETIME']
                hdf_store.append(group, data.loc[:,['R1', 'R2', 'R3']])

    # Adding sensor information as metadata to nodes
    for sens in sensors:
        try:
            hdf_store.get_storer(sens).attrs.metadata = sens_dict[sens]
            hdf_store.get_storer(sens).attrs['TITLE'] = sens
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

If I comment out the line `hdf_store.append(group, data.loc[:,['R1', 'R2', 'R3']])`, the bit under `for chunk in df:` takes about **40 - 45 seconds** to finish processing an iteration. (The chunk size I am reading is 1M rows.) But with the line included in the code (that is if the grouped chunk is being written to HDF file) the code takes about **10 - 12 minutes** for each iteration. I am completely baffled by the increase in execution time. I do not know what is causing that to happen.

Please give me some suggestions to resolve the issue. Note that I cannot afford execution times that long. I need to process about 220 GB of data in this fashion. Later I need to query that data, one node at a time, for further analysis. I have spent over 4 days researching the topic, but I am still as stumped as when I began.

**#### EDIT 1 ####**
Including `df.info()` for a chunk containing 1M rows.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1000000 entries, 0 to 999999
Data columns (total 7 columns):
SENSOR      1000000 non-null object
DATE        1000000 non-null datetime64[ns]
EPOCH       1000000 non-null timedelta64[ns]
R1          1000000 non-null float32
R2          773900 non-null float32
R3          483270 non-null float32
DATETIME    1000000 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float32(3), object(1), timedelta64[ns](1)
memory usage: 49.6+ MB
```

Of these, only `DATETIME, R1, R2, R3` are written to the file.

**#### EDIT 2 ####**
Including `pd.show_versions()`

```
 In [ ] : pd.show_versions()
Out [ ] : INSTALLED VERSIONS
          ------------------
          commit: None
          python: 3.4.3.final.0
          python-bits: 64
          OS: Windows
          OS-release: 8
          machine: AMD64
          processor: Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
          byteorder: little
          LC_ALL: None
          LANG: None

          pandas: 0.17.0
          nose: 1.3.7
          pip: 7.1.2
          setuptools: 18.4
          Cython: 0.23.2
          numpy: 1.10.1
          scipy: 0.16.0
          statsmodels: 0.6.1
          IPython: 4.0.0
          sphinx: 1.3.1
          patsy: 0.4.0
          dateutil: 2.4.1
          pytz: 2015.6
          blosc: None
          bottleneck: 1.0.0
          tables: 3.2.2
          numexpr: 2.4.4
          matplotlib: 1.4.3
          openpyxl: 2.0.2
          xlrd: 0.9.4
          xlwt: 1.0.0
          xlsxwriter: 0.7.3
          lxml: 3.4.4
          bs4: 4.3.2
          html5lib: None
          httplib2: None
          apiclient: None
          sqlalchemy: 1.0.8
          pymysql: None
          psycopg2: None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are constantly performing indexing the rows you write. It is much more efficient to write all of the rows, THEN create the index.

See the documentation on creating an index [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#indexing).

On the append operations pass `index=False`; this will turn off indexing.

Then when you are finally finished, run (on each node), assuming `store` is your `HDFStore`.

```
store.create_table_index('node')
```

This operation will take some time, but will be done once rather than continuously. This makes a tremendous difference because the creation can take into account all of your data (and move it only once).

You might also want to `ptrepack` your data (either before or after the indexing operation), to reset the `chunksize`. I wouldn't specify it directly, rather set `chunksize='auto'` to let it figure out an optimal size AFTER all of the data is written.

So this should be a pretty fast operation (even with indexing).

```
In [38]: N = 1000000

In [39]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(N,3).astype(np.float32),columns=list('ABC'),index=pd.date_range('20130101',freq='ms',periods=N))

In [40]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1000000 entries, 2013-01-01 00:00:00 to 2013-01-01 00:16:39.999000
Freq: L
Data columns (total 3 columns):
A    1000000 non-null float32
B    1000000 non-null float32
C    1000000 non-null float32
dtypes: float32(3)
memory usage: 19.1 MB

In [41]: store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5',mode='w')

In [42]: def write():
   ....:     for i in range(10):
   ....:         dfi = df.copy()
   ....:         dfi.index = df.index + pd.Timedelta(minutes=i)
   ....:         store.append('df',dfi)
   ....:         

In [43]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 write()
1 loops, best of 1: 4.26 s per loop

In [44]: store.close()

In [45]: pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df').info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 10000000 entries, 2013-01-01 00:00:00 to 2013-01-01 00:25:39.999000
Data columns (total 3 columns):
A    float32
B    float32
C    float32
dtypes: float32(3)
memory usage: 190.7 MB
```

Versions

```
In [46]: pd.__version__
Out[46]: u'0.17.0'

In [49]: import tables

In [50]: tables.__version__
Out[50]: '3.2.2'

In [51]: np.__version__
Out[51]: '1.10.1'
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I was hoping you would answer. One question, before I update my code to match your recommendation: Right now, I am converting the `'DATETIME'` field in my DataFrame into an index before writing. It is very important that the data be indexed by datatime, because these are timestamped data. By passing `index=False` will it ignore the datetime index column, or alter it in any way when I finally run `store.create_table_index('node')`?

Comment: Or would you rather recommend that I include `'DATETIME'` as a column in the data and later somehow convert it into an index? (Maybe using ptrepack...) I will anyway have to use ptrepack to compress the file after it is created.

Comment: no index=False just defers creating the on disk index itself (for the index of the frame and any data_columns you have created). The key point is that it's still indexed, just created after you write the data.

Comment: Still took a little over 7 minutes to write to disk. Indexing will take even longer after this. Are there any other optimization strategies that I can use?

Comment: prob quite inefficient to store 260k nodes; you are better off storing then in much fewer nodes I think

Comment: I put in an example. This only takes me 450ms to write a 1M chunk.

Comment: You example took 18.4s on my machine. Maybe because of hardware differences, or because I am running Windows? I don't know. My dataset took 6 min and 5 s for one run! Is it because 16k nodes were created? Indexing was turned off.